# Absolutely positioning background in responsive layout

Tags: css, css-position, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive layout and have positioned a grungy png overlay on top of background using the following CSS:

```
#bg{
   background:url(images/top1.png) no-repeat; 
   position:absolute; 
   width:1423px; 
   height:350px; 
   top:0; 
   left:50%; 
   margin-left: -711px;
}
```

This way, the image is always centered regardless of the page width. My problem occurs when the browser window is reduced to a width smaller than the background image for the `#bg` overlay. A horizontal scrollbar appears and the background extends far to the right (especially when the browser is very small).

You can see a DEMO of this here: http://pixelcakecreative.com/cimlife/responsive2/

As you can see a horizontal scrollbar appears, I would like browser window to shrink and not retain the full width of the image! Any ideas?

Comment: I added `max-width: 100%`, and the scrollbar becomes smaller, but not completely eliminated. (If you use JavaScript to respond, why can't you adapt the background with JS?)

Comment: Don't forget to add a type="text" to your textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css code:

```
      #bg{
 background:url(images/top1.png) no-repeat center;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:350px;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 }
```

Comment: this does fix it, however when the browser is small enough, another horizontal scrollbar appears. Any idea why? It is not because of the absolutely positioned bg, but something else.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look at your code. Check out your nav, this one produces the scrollbar.

Have a look on how to enable developer tools in your browser to inspect your page. It's a good way to check on your elements attributes.

Here's an good introduction for Chrome: [Link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/)

And for Safari: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html)